# C# - Match If Value in a Dictionary<string,string> match with specified string

Tags: c#, regex

Basically I have some products in a SQL table already grouped in to some categories. For example Laptops, Cameras, MP3 Players etc. Now when I take products in one of these category (Laptops for example) I need to further drill down them based on their features/options. (Example - RAM size(1 GB, 4 GB,..), Processor Type(Core i7, Core i3..), Hard Drive Size(250 GB, 500 GB) etc.). Initially I did this categorization using MSSQL's `Contains('COLUMNNAME', 'FormsOf(Inflectional, SOMEWORD))`. This approach works but it takes nearly 8Hrs to finish all the records in my database. (300K records)

So now I'm thinking of a Regex based implementation for the same. So here is what I came up with so far. May be its much clear is with this code.

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var productList = new Dictionary<string, string>
                                  {
                                      {"10101", "Samsung NF210 Netbook - 10.1ins - 1GB RAM - 250GB Hard Drive"},
                                      {"10102", "Samsung NP-NF210 Netbook, Intel Atom 1.5GHz, 1GB RAM, 250GB with 10.1 Inch Display, Silver"},
                                      {"10103", "Sony Vaio VPC-F13Z0E/B Laptop, Intel Core i7, 1.73GHz, 6GB RAM, 640GB with 16.4 Inch Display, Black"}
                                  };

            var featureList = new Dictionary<int, string>
                                  {
                                      {1, "1 GB"}, // RAM SIZE
                                      {2, "2 GB"}, // RAM SIZE
                                      {3, "250GB"}, // HARD DRIVE SIZE
                                      {4, "640GB"}, // HARD DRIVE SIZE
                                      {5,"Core i7"}, // Porcessor Type
                                      {6,"Core i3"}, // Porcessor Type
                                      {7,"Netbook"}, // Type
                                      {8,"Laptop"} // Type
                                  };

            foreach (var feature in featureList)
            {
                var keyword1 = feature;

                var results = from result in productList
                              where Regex.IsMatch(result.Value, keyword1.Value, RegexOptions.Singleline)
                              select result;

                foreach (var result in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(feature.Key + " - " + feature.Value);
                    Console.WriteLine(result.Key + " - " + result.Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }  
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

So my real question now, will this approach works or not? I know the way I have done is not as good as `SQL Contains` but it seems working. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Note: A dictionary is built on the idea of fast lookups based on the *unique key*. When your logic instead focuses on the value, you may be using the wrong tool, or the wrong methodology.

Comment: If your question is : Is Regex the best approach to text searching then i would say yes.

Comment: Have you tried executing the line `var results = ...` I believe you will get an exception. And you will be constantly updating/maintaining that Regex.

Comment: The reason why I used a Dictionary is I want to store the SQL `ProductId` and `featureId` (SQL Products,Feature tables) to another mapping table (ProductFeatures) after matching the records.

Comment: @IAbstract - Well, there is no exception actually.

Comment: I guess Linq2Objects plays nicer with Regex than Linq2Sql: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5720987/210709

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex for this is incredibly overkill, and a security hole.

Use `String.Contains`.