# Linq2Sql match regex using SqlMethods.Like

Tags: regex, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to return all rows in a table which DOES NOT match the pattern. The pattern is [0-9]\w[A-Za-z0-9].

Some examples of the matched string:

- 7145840 ABC Plumbers
- 1232433 Company
- 123213 Another 123 Test

What we're specifically looking for is that it starts with a set of numbers, followed with a whitespace and then a set of mixed characters (can be alphanumeric with whitespaces, as long as starts with the correct pattern).

My query below currently returns ALL of the results which hints that my regex is wrong? It may be due to the \ as I need to escape the \ but not sure?

```
  var CustomerMask = Regex.Escape("[0-9]+\\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
        var query = (from s in db.Stagings
                     where !SqlMethods.Like(s.CustomerCode,CustomerMask)
                     select s
            );

        var c = query.Count();
```

Comment: *The pattern, which may include **wildcard** characters* - `Like` does not support  a *regular expression*. Besides, you escape the regex pattern containing regex constructs. *Like* wildcards do not support quantifiers and shorthands like `\s`.

Comment: I was not sure whether I needed to specifically escape the string prior to using it within the linq query. Am I right to then assume this cannot be done?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5721097/3832970 saying "No".